# How to configure a React app for different environments

Tags: configuration, react

We're configuring the build and release pipeline for our frontend code which is built with React. The final output is just some static HTML/Javascript code. The differences between environments are extremely small - for example, our `dev` environment will produce code that makes API calls to `dev.oursite.com` and likewise for staging, etc.

Is it best to have configuration for our different environments applied at build time or run time? For example, we could have a config.js that looks *something* like this:

```
{"dev": {"thing1": "value_dev", ...}, "prod": {"thing1": "value_prod", ...}
```

The problem is this means we will have a different build for each environment, each will differ by something like a `--env dev` flag. The output of each build will be extremely similar. Each build would have its own release stage (which all will be pretty much identical).

A different solution would be to try to make a generic build which could be promoted to different release environments, and that build would get tweaked based on the release environment. For example, instead of `value_dev`/`value_prod` being placed in the build, our generic build could have `__THING1_VALUE_REPLACE_ME__` which is meaningless and, at release time, we do a `sed` replace (or equivalent) to populate the proper values. In this scenario we only build once and we follow https://12factor.net/ more closely.

Comment: Well, asking for _best practices_ almost always is a _big no-no_, and comes up to be _opinion based_.

Comment: The question "Is it best to have configuration for our different environments applied at build time or run time" depends on what your specific needs are.

Comment: Honestly, I am curious what the answer is to this myself.  I have opinions on what I would like to happen, but the feasibility of it really depends on your technology stack.

Comment: Perhaps if the question were re-titled to "How to I configure a React app for different environments?" the trigger word of "best practices" would be removed and the question would cease to be downvoted

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: When I see the words "best practices" in a question, I look for the author's decision-making process: what criteria will they use to decide what is best practice and what isn't?  Usually, no criteria is specified.  Popularity (the assumptive criteria in any "best practice" pleading) is seldom a satisfactory reason for making *any* decision.  Were that the case, we'd all be using Java or C.  So it's not merely about removing the words "best practice" from a question; it's about clarifying the asker's intentions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, My comment was directed to the OP to help them fix the question to fit our format.  I don't disagree with you on the words "best practice"

Answer (score 2):

**Prefix**

I don't think there is a best practice for environment configurations. I will say there is a handful of tradeoffs and limitations imposed by frameworks, build processes, and languages. These will all play a factor in crafting your CI/CD solution. Also, I will note a more simplistic solution might be a better fit for a smaller resource stricken company/team.

**Scenario**

Let's say you have 3 boxes for 3 environments:

- Staging
- User Acceptance Testing
- Production

**Runtime Injection**

If you're doing a runtime injection each of those boxes will have to have references to the configurations. This creates a non-centralized configuration scheme. This can pose a problem if you have to scale horizontally. Now you have 3xn configurations to manage. If you don't plan on scaling horizontally there is a benefit to this architecture, you can change an environment variable without having to redeploy. You simply modify the variable and restart the application.

I have seen runtime configurations stored in a central location but the application must compensate. This creates complexity and can lead to configuration drift where the runtime is using an out-of-date configuration.

**Build Time Injection**

If you're doing build time injection. You will have the benefit of centralizing configurations in your build server. Another benefit is the coupling between deployments and environment variables. The tradeoff is you must redeploy the application to change a variable.

**Suffix**

I personally have my configuration baked into my build process. I use containers for my applications and I must ship images preconfigured. I've found this a more common pattern at scale, but for a small application, I could see myself choosing a simpler architecture.

I would lookup **Configuration Drift** & how containers handle deployment configurations. It will likely shape your solution.